# Partition function proof

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I am looking for any online information regarding Hardy and Ramanujan's proof, perhaps the proof itself, that the partition function $p(n)$ is asymptotic to 
$$\frac{e^{K\sqrt{n}}}{4n\sqrt{3}}$$
where $K=\pi\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$.
Online references help because I don't have a lot of time to spend at my university library, although I do have time to check the materials out and work from home.  I've tried finding it but my luck has not been good:
I also understand that Erdos also has a proof.

$\mathbf{EDIT}$:  I would also be happy with online (or library) material that leads up to the development of the proof so that I could study it as well.

Comment: You can buy it [here](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0821820230/ref=nosim/weisstein-20) or try to find that book elsewehere. The pages you are after are unfortunately not availiable in the preview.

Comment: that's unfortunate.  I appreciate the help

Comment: Hardy and Ramanujan’s 1918 paper is here: http://www.doc88.com/p-7982900471065.html. I won’t speculate on whether it’s legal to be available at that link.